# Rails - Method that returns true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to create a method that returns true or false, but it's return neither, what am I doing wrong?

In the controller:

```
valid_email_domain(email.to_s)

protected
  def valid_email_domain(emailAddy)
    reg = Regexp.new /#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join("|")}/
    Rails.logger.info 'REGEX TIME'
    Rails.logger.info emailAddy.scan(reg).size    
    if emailAddy.scan(reg).size == 0
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

valid_email_domain isn't return anything. What's the issue? Thanks

Comment: Show the controller code, how do you reference the model?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you should brush up your ruby.

Comment: @vise how so? Im here to learn.

Comment: @Satya this is all in the controller right now

Comment: AnApprentice: The reason he's saying that is your last line, `emailAddy.scan(reg).size == 0` will already return true or false, and whatever your last line of code is in a Ruby method is what the method itself will return by default. In other words, as in Jacob Relkin's answer below, you don't need the If...Else block at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def valid_email_domain?(emailAddy)
   reg = Regexp.new /#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join("|")}/
   Rails.logger.info 'REGEX TIME'
   Rails.logger.info emailAddy.scan(reg).size    
   emailAddy.scan(reg).size == 0
end
```

As a side point, a common method naming convention in Ruby is to use a trailing `?` for methods that return a boolean.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I was adding the ? after the paratheses.

Comment: Looks like something's wrong with the REGEX though, started another thread since as you've pointed out that's a different question. If the email doesn't match INVALID_EMAILS, it's hanging